# How to use an existing Realm as a resource

Tags: android, realm

I would like to put a Realm database which already has some data into Android's `assets` folder as a read-only resource file, what should I do?

Comment: See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#read-only-realms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#read-only-realms

You can put the `the_realm.realm` file into the `/assets` folder

Then you can build a configuration (which makes it `readOnly()` as well) like so

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
    .assetFile("the_realm.realm")
    .readOnly()
    // It is optional, but recommended to create a module that describes the classes
    // found in your bundled file. Otherwise if your app contains other classes
    // than those found in the file, it will crash when opening the Realm as the
    // schema cannot be updated in read-only mode.
    .modules(new BundledRealmModule())
    .build();
```

Then `BundledRealmModule` would be like

```
@RealmModule(classes={Dog.class, Cat.class})
public class BundledRealmModule {
}
```

Comment: Thx you ! It works for me, I thought it will create a new Realm to instead my resource realm before